# Two equations and two unknowns does not give expected knowns

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following drawing area in Inkscape. which is 40 cells wide and 19 cells high.

[image]

This design is to be printed on a mug. It (the big white area) consists of 6 rectangles divided by the vertical lines (guides). The two red squares are for placement of logos. The area containing a logo is 8 cells, and the other 4 areas are 6 cells wide each. This is confirmed by the following sum:

$$
2\times 8 + 4\times 6 = 40
$$

So, I thought I could have calculated the values for $x$ (take it as width for the area containing logo) and $y$ (take it as width of the 4 remaining areas) using two equations and two unknowns, rather than experimenting in the software, as shown below:
\begin{align*}
2x + 4y & = 40\\  
x + 2y  & = 20
\end{align*}

---

Solving these two equations by first multiplying -2 by the second row gives the following:

\begin{align*}
2x+4y & =40\\
-2x-4y & =-40
\end{align*}

Which, after adding the two rows, results in the following:  $0-0=0$.

However, this does not seem to lead anywhere.

Can this problem be solved using two equations and two unknowns in the first place?

What is your recommended way to solve this problem?

Comment: You don't really have two equations, since one is derived from the other, through multiplication by a constant (ie 2). The best you can hope for is a functional relationship between $x$ and $y$, e.g. $x = 20 - 2 y$.  However I must confess that I don't quite see what you plan to achieve, maybe some context might make it clearer.

Comment: I want to achieve x=8 and y=6 using two equations and two unknowns. However, I guess the knowns are not enough to achieve this result.

Comment: @MehdiHaghgoo $x=8$ and $y=6$ is a system of two equations and two unknowns. They're already solved a well.

Comment: It took me a while to realize the areas you're talking about are the rectangles divided by the vertical lines. An edit to your question about that might help.

Comment: You have only one equation really, and this also has other valid solutions such as $x=10$, $y=5$. With this solution the two regions containing the logo areas are wider, so the logo's could then be made larger. I suspect that you really want $x$ to match the size of some given logo, and then you can calculate the width of the blank strips by $y=10-x/2$.